# Ransack search by a selected column dynamicaly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

i want to do a search with Ransack in a User model, but i need a select with the attributes of the model as options to perform the search for that model. So if i have as attributes `name, last_name, email` the select should have this fields to be selected and next to it an input field to write the text that i want to search in the selected column or attribute for the User model.

Is there a way to do it with Ransack in Rails 4.1?

I think that could be something like this

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :selected_field, collection_of_attributes %>
  <%= f.search_field :user_selected_field_cont %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using ransack's attribute_select. http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack?view=asciicast

Comment: thanks for your answer, but you were almost there, because i've seen that railscasts, but i don't know how to remove that `<%= c.predicate_select %>` and search always as a `_cont`search =/

Comment: Instead of the predicate field use a hidden input